# Changes to the lock_wait_timeout variable in MySQL not being reflected in Django app

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

I've been trying to change the lock_wait_timeout variable in MySQL because the default value of 50 seconds is not suitable for my Django application.

I've used the following commands:

```
set innodb_lock_wait_timeout=2;
show variables like 'innodb_lock_wait_timeout';
```

Although the show variables command confirms that my changes have been made, the timeout is still 50 seconds when my Django app is trying to acquire a lock on a locked record.

This is the code snippet that I'm using to lock a particular record using Django:

```
form = Form.objects.select_for_update().filter(id = form_details[FORM_ID]).first()
```

I've tried restarting the MySQL service and even restarting my whole system, all to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL variables are either session or global.

'set X=y' is setting the session variable X only. Django creates a new session so is unaffected.

Use:

```
set global innodb_lock_wait_timeout=2;
show global variables like 'innodb_lock_wait_timeout';
```

Global variables are copied to session variables at the start of the connection. If you want it to affect Django only you'll need to do something manually in your code at the beginning of the connection.